# Anna and Carlos are discussing a graph with 17 vertices and 129 edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Anna and Carlos are talking about a graph with 17 vertices and 129 edges. One of them says that it must be a Hamiltonian graph, while the other say's it's not. With no other information about the graph, is one of them right? Or is it impossible to tell with no other information? Why or why not?

Comment: are you sure you wrote the question correctly?

Comment: Yep, basically one of them is saying that the graph is Hamiltonian, while the other says it's not.

Comment: One of them is always correct then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of them must always be correct. Suppose Anna says it is Hamiltonian and Carlos says it is not. If the graph is indeed Hamiltonian then Anna right. If it is not Hamiltonian then Carlos is right.

In this case we can prove Anna is right though, in fact the graph can have as little as $122$ edges (The number was presumambly left as $129$ so it could be solved with [Dirac's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiracsTheorem.html)). $K_{17}$ has $136$ edges, so at most $14$ are missing. This reduces the sum of the degrees of two vertices by at most $15$. Therefore the sum of the degrees of any two vertices is at least $32-15=17\geq 17$. [Ore's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem) proves the graph is Hamiltonian.

The bound is sharp, the graph on $121$ edges that removes $15$ edges from a single vertex is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: I was thinking that there's not enough info to get if it's Hamiltonian or not, since there's no algorithm for determining Hamiltonian graphs (unlike Eulerian graphs).

Comment: There is no "efficient" algorithm for determining whether an arbitrary graph is hamiltonian or not. But there are various results that tell us if  each vertex has a lot of edges then it must be hamiltonian. Of course only a small fraction of hamiltonian graphs satisfy those conditions.

Comment: What did you mean by 9 missing edges?

Comment: The graph in question has all of the edges of $K_{17}$ except for $9$.

Comment: @TheirEmperorofIceCream, isn't it 7 missing edges?

Comment: Oh yeah, if it has $7$ missing edges you can prove it using Dirac, you don't need Ore.

Comment: Ok, so then n=17 vertices. Each vertex of G has degree that is greater than or equal to n/2 = 8.5?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding Dirac? Once I know that we have 129 edges, which is 7 less than 136 edges, what do I do?

Comment: Since the degree of a vertex in $K_{17}$ is $16$, once you take $7$ edges away every vertex has at least degree $16-7=9>8.5$ so by Dirac it is hamiltonian.